# Is it posible to use AM/FM antenna as GPS antenna?

Tags: signal, radio, gps

Having installed a tablet (Nexus 7) in the car dashboard, the GPS receiving signal seems to be too weak (specially in places with lots of buildings/trees around). So I thought about opening the tablet and connect the built-in GPS antenna contact points in the SoC with the car built-in antenna.

However the GPS and AM/FM signal frequencies are different, so I guess the car antenna would be designed just for radio signals, making it not work with GPS.

In addition, the car antenna is located in the very top of the vehicle, so over 1 meter wire would be necessary to make a connection with the tablet, which makes me suppose I would need some kind of amplifier due to power loss in the wire

So, I wonder if that is possible and, if it would be effective

Comment: Possible?  Perhaps.  Advisable?   No, neither the antenna nor the coax are designed for the frequencies in question.  Besides you're more likely to damage the tablet than successfully connect to the right antenna port.

Comment: Can you pair a bluetooth GPS receiver?

Comment: You can get GPS repeaters for this putpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it would work.

No it would not work ***effectively***.

There are antennas designed for GPS applications. Or you could get a USB or Bluetooth GPS module and connect that to your tablet.